# hibernate: unexpected token error on custom query

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm trying to make a double inner join on my entities

BundleRepository:

```
@Query("select b from Bundle b inner join BundlePlan p ON b.bundle_code = p.bundle_code "
        + "inner join PlanBenefit e ON p.plan_code = e.plan_code"
        + "where b.bundle_code = ?1")
List<Bundle> findBundlePlanInfo(String bundle_code);
```

BundleService:

```
public List<Bundle> getBundlePlanInfoByBundleCode(String bundle_code);
```

BundleServiceImpl:

```
@Override
public List<Bundle> getBundlePlanInfoByBundleCode(String bundle_code) {
    return (List<Bundle>) bundleRepository.findBundlePlanInfo(bundle_code);
}
```

BundleController:

```
@RequestMapping(value="Bundle/{bundle_code}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView bundleProfile(@PathVariable("bundle_code") String bundle_code) {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("bundle_profile");
    List<Bundle> bundlePlanInfo = bundleService.getBundlePlanInfoByBundleCode(bundle_code);
    model.addObject("bundlePlanInfo",bundlePlanInfo);

    return model;
}
```

And I'm giving several errors like this

```
unexpected token: b near line 1, column 212 [select b from com.rtc_insurance.model.Bundle b inner join com.rtc_insurance.model.BundlePlan p ON b.bundle_code = p.bundle_code inner join com.rtc_insurance.model.PlanBenefit e ON p.plan_code = e.plan_codewhere b.bundle_code = ?1]
```

and this

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bundleController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'bundleService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bundleServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'bundleRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bundleRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.rtc_insurance.repository.BundleRepository.findBundlePlanInfo(java.lang.String)!
```

Comment: Add a space before the start of `where` condition. `+ " where b.bundle_code = ?1"`

Comment: thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*unexpected token: b* clearly gives hint that there is some problem with `b.bundle_code`.

Give space before where clause like below.

```
@Query("select b from Bundle b inner join BundlePlan p ON b.bundle_code = p.bundle_code "
        + "inner join PlanBenefit e ON p.plan_code = e.plan_code"
        + " where b.bundle_code = ?1")
```